# Swift, enum doesn't work inside a struct. Errors: Type '<enum name>' has no member '<enum member>', Cannot find '<enum name>' in scope

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I am learning Swift and encountered a problem while doing a project from Codecademy to practice enumerations. I have an enum inside a struct, but cannot create an instance of it with any member of enum.

Errors are marked with ️ in comments - last three lines under tests comment.

This is my code:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Ingredient {
    var name: String
    var quantity: Double
    var unit: Unit
    
    var description: String {
        let formattedQuantity = String(format: "%g", quantity)
        
        switch unit {
        case .none:
            let formattedName = quantity == 1 ? name : "\(name)s"
            return "\(formattedQuantity) \(formattedName)"
        default:
            if quantity == 1 {
                return "1 \(unit.singularName) \(name)"
            } else {
                return "\(formattedQuantity) \(unit.rawValue) \(name)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum Unit: String, CaseIterable {
        case oz = "Ounces"
        case g = "Grams"
        case cups = "Cups"
        case tbs = "Tablespoons"
        case tsp = "Teaspoons"
        case none = "No units"
        
        var singularName: String {String(rawValue.dropLast())}
    }
}


// tests
let myIngredient = Ingredient(name: "Sugar", quantity: 2.0, unit: Unit.tbs) //️ Error: Type 'Unit' has no member 'tbs'
print(myIngredient.description) // ️ Error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level

let myFourthIngredient = Ingredient(name: "Banana", quantity: 1.0, unit: Unit.allCases) //️ Error: Type 'Unit' has no member 'allCases'
```

How can I fix errors and keep enum inside the struct?

---

I tried to create a similar struct and had a different error, but a close one:

```swift
struct Fruits {
    var name: String
    var apple: Apple
    
    enum Apple: String, CaseIterable {
        case red = "Red"
        case green = "green"
    }
}

let test = Fruits(name: "Apple", apple: Apple.red) // ️Error: Cannot find 'Apple' in scope
print(test.apple.rawValue)
```

However, when I move enum outside of struct, it works fine. But is it possible to access enum inside of struct?

Comment: `Inngredient.Unit.tbs`, or just `.tbs` (since it knows it's an `Ingredient.Unit`) should do the trick

Comment: regarding "Error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level": are you doing this in an app project? I think you mean to do it in a Playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up your scopes.

You either need use just the case or, as you are outside of the Struct referencing an internal type, give it its full denomination...

```
let test = Fruits(name: "Apple", apple: .red)
```

where the type can be inferred by the compiler,

or specify it completely.

```
let test = Fruits(name: "Apple", apple: Fruits.Apple.red)
```